# "Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable."

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to build a container image that I will later use to update the code inside of a virtual machine. The docker image works fine as I can build and run it inside of my terminal. However, I keep getting an error when I try to deploy it to cloud run: "Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable." How can I fix this error?

The build log contains this:

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [SERVICE] in project [PROJECT_ID] region [REGION]
Deploying...
Creating Revision.......................................................................................................................................................................failed
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

The revision log contains this:

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 9,
      "message": "Ready condition status changed to False for Revision {REVISION_NAME} with message: Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL:{URL_LINK}"
    },
    "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com",
    "resourceName": "{REVISION_NAME}",
    "response": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "{REVISION_NAME}",
        "namespace": "{NAMESPACE}",
        "selfLink": "{SELFLINK}",
        "uid": "{UID}",
        "resourceVersion": "{RESOURCEVER}",
        "generation": 1,
        "creationTimestamp": "{TIMESTAMP}",
        "labels": {
          "serving.knative.dev/route": "{SERVICE}",
          "serving.knative.dev/configuration": "{SERVICE}",
          "serving.knative.dev/configurationGeneration": "15",
          "serving.knative.dev/service": "{SERVICE}",
          "serving.knative.dev/serviceUid": "{SERVICE_UID}",
          "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "{REGION}"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "run.googleapis.com/client-name": "gcloud",
          "serving.knative.dev/creator": "{NAMESPACE}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com",
          "client.knative.dev/user-image": "gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{IMAGE}",
          "run.googleapis.com/client-version": "357.0.0",
          "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale": "100"
        },
        "ownerReferences": [
          {
            "kind": "Configuration",
            "name": "{SERVICE}",
            "uid": "{UID}",
            "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
            "controller": true,
            "blockOwnerDeletion": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
      "kind": "Revision",
      "spec": {
        "containerConcurrency": 80,
        "timeoutSeconds": 300,
        "serviceAccountName": "{NAMESPACE}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "containers": [
          {
            "image": "gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{IMAGE}",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "h2c",
                "containerPort": 8080
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "1000m",
                "memory": "512Mi"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "status": {
        "observedGeneration": 1,
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "Ready",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL:{LOG_LINK}",
            "lastTransitionTime": "{TIME}"
          },
          {
            "type": "Active",
            "status": "Unknown",
            "reason": "Reserve",
            "lastTransitionTime": "{TIME}",
            "severity": "Info"
          },
          {
            "type": "ContainerHealthy",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL:{LOG_LINK}",
            "lastTransitionTime": "{TIME}"
          },
          {
            "type": "ResourcesAvailable",
            "status": "True",
            "lastTransitionTime": "{TIME}"
          },
          {
            "type": "Retry",
            "status": "True",
            "reason": "ImmediateRetry",
            "message": "System will retry after 0:00:00 from lastTransitionTime for attempt 0.",
            "lastTransitionTime": "{TIME}",
            "severity": "Info"
          }
        ],
        "logUrl": "{LOG_LINK}",
        "imageDigest": "gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{IMAGE_SHA}"
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.run.v1.Revision"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "{ID}",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "location": "{REGION}",
      "configuration_name": "{SERVICE}",
      "service_name": "{SERVICE}",
      "project_id": "{PROJECT_ID}",
      "revision_name": "{REVISION_NAME}"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "{TIME}",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/{PROJECT_ID}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event",
  "receiveTimestamp": "{TIME}"
}
```

This is my cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE', '.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE']
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'SERVICE-NAME', '--image', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE', '--region', 'REGION', '--port', '8080']
images:
- gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "hello.py" ]
```

This is the code in hello.py:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Cloud Run starts your container, a health check is sent to the container. Your container is not responding to the health check. Therefore, Cloud Run determines that your service is failing.

Cloud Run requires that a container provide service/process/program that listens for and responds to HTTP requests.

Your hello.py file only prints a message to stdout. Your program does not start a process to listen for requests.

A very simple example that converts your example into a working program:

```
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
        return "Hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

Note: You will need to add a file **requirements.txt** to your build to include Flask. Create **requirements.txt** in the same location as **Dockerfile**.

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==2.0.1
```